# Jackrabbit XPath query throws exception after ugrade to JR 2.4.2

Tags: xpath, jackrabbit, magnolia

We are currently working on upgrading Jackrabbit from 1.6.5 to 2.4.2 on our system. we are facing problems on some XPath queries that used to work on the 1.6.5 perfectly, and now it throws javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException exception on 2.4.2 - do Jackrabbit changed the way how it parse the XPath queries?

the query is:

```
//programs//*[child::*/@sunday]
```

on version 1.6.5 returns:

```
0 nodes returned in 1ms
```

and on 2.4.2 returns:

```
null for statement: for $v in //programs//*[child::*/@sunday] return $v
```

Comment: Release notes could help what the changes, fixes done in the later release.

Comment: XPath is deprecated in JCR 2.0 (which is implemented as Jackrabbit 2.4.2) in favor of JCR-SQL2, but I would think it would still work for you.  See http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/deprecated-list.html.  I'm not specifically familiar with Magnolia: is there perhaps an installation option that forces the fail on deprecated features?